# Uncaught TypeError: $(this).search is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

Uncaught TypeError: $(this).search is not a function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#caption').on('keypress', function () { 
            var n = $(this).search('#');
            if(n != "-1"){
                window.alert("There's a hash");
            }else{
                 window.alert("There's not a hash");
            }


    });
});
```

Comment: What is `#caption`, and in what way are you searching for `#`? Is it the value, the HTML, or an attribute?

Comment: # is the value of textarea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`search` is a JavaScript method for a string type.

So if you want to use `search`, your line `var n = $(this).search('#');` should be changed to `var n = $(this).val().search('#');` or `var n = $(this).text().search('#');` depending on the tag of `#caption` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [indexof()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp), if you want search in your input the character `#`.

Remember, [search()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) is used to regular expression. Otherwise [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) is going to be faster.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#caption').on('keypress', function () { 
        var n = $(this).val();
        if(n.indexOf("#") > -1){
            window.alert("There's a hash");
        }else{
             window.alert("There's not a hash");
        }

   });
});
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/3v04fvmb/